# nginx redirection to index page

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I am struggling to implement an automatic nginx redirect from non index pages to my index page, with the exception of /admin

For instance, example.com/test should redirect to example.com, but example.com/admin should not redirect to example.com

This is my current nginx configuration file:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/tmp/mysite.sock;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/www/example.com/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off; 

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    # redirects both www and non-www to https
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name  www.example.com;
    
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/example.com/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/example.com/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding a `try_files` statetement within my `location /` block, and other things, but none seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mix `proxy_pass` with `try_files`, it won't work within the same `location` block. You can use named location instead and rewrite any URI that doesn't start with `/admin` to a root one using negative regex assertion:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
}
location @app {
    rewrite ^(?!/admin) / break;
    proxy_cache my_cache;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

You don't need the separate `location /media { ... }` or `location /static { ... }` blocks, because as nginx documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias):

> When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     alias /data/w3/images/;
> }
> ```
>
> it is better to use the [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive instead:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```

Instead you just need to define the common server root (outside of any `location` blocks):

```
root /var/www/example.com;
```

You are also don't need to use the `proxy_ssl_server_name` directive since you are not proxying your request to the upstream with HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, it works like a charm. Thank you also for the recommendation on root instead of alias. (As expected), it won't work for a non-existent resource behind admin (for instance: https://www.example.com/admin/wrongurl). Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: @NicolasBerthier How do you want that type of URI to be processed? As `/admin` instead of `/admin/wrongurl`? You can add as the first rewrite rule `rewrite ^/admin.* /admin break;`

Comment: I think I didn't explain my issue properly, my bad :). Is there a way to redirect all (and only) non working resources to ```/```? As I am running a Django application, I have a couple of working resources behind ```/admin``` such as, for instance https://www.example.com/admin/auth/user/1/change/. I'd like for instance https://www.example.com/admin/auth/user/1/change/ to work but not https://www.example.com/admin/wrongurl.

Comment: @NicolasBerthier I can see two different appoaches. The first is to filter all the URIs by some kind of regular expression (maybe with the help of [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) block). This one can be used if you know all the URIs you want to pass to your backend. The second is to pass all requests to a backend and then behave according to HTTP result code returned from the upstream.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. I have solved my problem by using your solution and adding the admin URI of my Django app behind a "secret" URL